# React pending request to server when deployed to GCP App Engine

Tags: reactjs, server, fastapi, favicon

I deployed a React + FastAPI app to GCP app engine. However, I'm getting a HTTP Status Code 500 which's an internal server error and I checked the problem and found out that the favicon.ico is pending all the time or get 404 error.

You can check the app.js and the message.js in the components folder which includes the request: https://github.com/SaudC21/simple-react-app

Here is my FastAPI code (Server side):
https://github.com/SaudC21/simple-fastapi-app/blob/main/main.py

This is the log from GCP:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT0Jk.png)

This is the error from the browser: [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPu7I.png)

Comment: This is not what a minimal reproducible example looks like. The FastAPI code you gave is super generic and doesn't produce any errors (obviously). You are saying you are running a front end and a backend. The favicon.ico is part of your frontend, not fastapi. If you are getting a 500 error code in your FastAPI application, please provide us with the actual error and the relevant code.

Comment: A missing favicon should not cause a 500 error. Can you check the application logs in GCP for error messages?

Comment: @M.O. Here is an image of the logs in GCP: https://ibb.co/MGmSX2k

Comment: @JarroVGIT You can check the github the link on the notes up there.

Comment: Yeah I’m not gonna review your entire project. Here is what is going wrong: somewhere your front end thinks it should get the favicon from the backend. Maybe it’s a url mix up, maybe your front end is running on the same domain. It could be anything, but that is where you should start looking. Try to see what url is requested from the browser when requesting favicon and try to reason why that is routed to your backend and not your front end.

Comment: Well a quick look at your index.html shows what is going on; you are providing the backend url when building the react app probably

Comment: Thanks @JarroVGIT for your informative feedback. I guess now you'll have and others a better sense of the problem

Comment: Thanks @M.O. for your informative feedback. I guess now you'll have and others a better sense of the problem

Answer (score 0):

maybe the response should be a dict, can you try with

```
return {"Hello World": "From Server!"}
```